# PL/SQL Trigger not working - issue with setting variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

my trigger doesn't work, when I try to update a query. Any ideas why?
I feel like it is related to the WHERE conditions when I try to set variables.
I tried to do it without the WHERE conditions, but it still didn't work.

Any ideas why? Thank You!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYSTEM.Product_Price_Check
BEFORE UPDATE ON SYSTEM.product FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE     
min_price NUMBER(19,4); 
new_price NUMBER(19,4);

BEGIN 

    SELECT (StandardCost*1.2)
    INTO min_price
    FROM SYSTEM.product
    WHERE ProductID = :new.ProductID;

    SELECT ListPrice    
    INTO new_price
    FROM SYSTEM.product
    WHERE ProductID = :new.ProductID;

    IF new_price < min_price THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the price can’t be below '||CAST(min_price as VARCHAR(25)));
        --RAISE VALUE_ERROR;

    --ELSE
       --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Price was successfully changed');

    END IF;


END;
```

Comment: For future reference **do not build objects in the SYSTEM schema**. That schema is maintained by Oracle. Using it for your application code risks corrupting your database, and may create problems with support. Create a user for your application code and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is a homework assignment and you have been told to use a trigger. Long years on this site have taught me that teachers love setting assignments which demand the misuse of triggers.

In real life the only correct way to enforce such a rule is with a check constraint:

```
alter table product add constraint price_check 
    check (standard_cost * 1.2 >= min_price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Show your error.
Probably your trigger is [mutating](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#g1699708)

> The session that issued the triggering statement cannot query or modify a mutating table. This restriction prevents a trigger from seeing an inconsistent set of data.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you should not be creating objects such as tables or triggers in the SYSTEM schema. Create yourself a user, grant it the necessary privileges (good practice), and use that user and its schema for development purposes.

Next - in a row triggers (one with `FOR EACH ROW` in it) you cannot access the table upon which the trigger is defined, which in this case is the PRODUCT table. Fortunately, you don't really need to. The values you want are already in the :OLD or :NEW pseudo-rows - I'm guessing here that you really want to use the :NEW values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PRODUCT_PRICE_CHECK
  BEFORE UPDATE ON PRODUCT
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  nMin_price NUMBER := :NEW.STANDARD_COST * 1.2;
BEGIN 
    IF :NEW.LISTPRICE < nMin_price THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('List price can’t be below '|| nMin_price);

      RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
END PRICE_CHECK;
```

Also, you can't execute a ROLLBACK or COMMIT in a trigger - Oracle doesn't allow this to happen.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `RAISE VALUE_ERROR` instead of `raise_application_error` which would let you include a more appropriate message?

Comment: OP had this (commented out) in his original code. I thought I'd stick with it for the example.